# Thumnail image in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website using wordpress and bootstrap 3, but i have some issue with Featured Images on my template.

In the blog homepage i'd want display the "bootstrap-medium" size (see the code below), and in the article page i'd want display the "bootstrap-large" size. 
At the time i'm displaying the same resolution (bootstrap-large) in both of page. 
Where i did it wrong?

[functions.php](http://pastebin.com/XddnXGep)

[page.php](http://pastebin.com/gMQixLdg)

Waiting for your help. Thanks In advice

Comment: In both the codes I see `bootstrap-medium`

Comment: Where is your functions.php code???

Comment: Sorry i've messed up the first link.... now the links should work fine

Comment: With first glance I notice that you use cwd_wp_bootstrapwp_is_post_thumbnail_set() to check if there is a featured image or not. You can use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail. I know it isn't relative to your problem but I thought it can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but this isn't the problem